# Pressing toggle button affects position of div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried searching for other questions that have been asked before, but I can't seem to find one that's relevant to my situation. I'll try my best to explain.

I want to be able to press the 'Tuner On' button in my project where it toggles between clearing the rectangular beige screen of any text, but at the same time, to not change the position of where it says "Metronome" at the top right corner. Every time I press the 'Tuner On' toggle button, it moves the 'Metronome' rectangle up while it clears the letter 'A'.

How do I make it so that the toggle button does not change the 'Metronome' position?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.GreyRectangle1").click(function() {
    $("div.ReceivedNote").toggleClass('ReceivedNote1');
  })
})
```

```css
.ReceivedNote {
  z-index: 4;
}

.ReceivedNote1 {
  display: none;
}

.metronome-box {
  position: fixed;
}

.Metronome {
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transform: scaleX(1.2);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  height: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 185px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Orange">
  <div class="ReceivedNote">A</div>
  <div class="metronome-box">
    <div class="Metronome">METRONOME</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="top-trapezoid"></div>
<div class="right-trapezoid"></div>
<div class="bottom-trapezoid"></div>
<div class="left-trapezoid"></div>
<p class="tuner-on">TUNER ON</p>
<button class="GreyRectangle1">
  <div class="InnerGreyDot" style="margin-top: 2px;"></div>
</button>
```

[my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrwg38z6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it didn't work. I did solve it however finding another person's question by using 'visibility:hidden'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I will fix the answer. My mind was thinking of borders, where you set the color without changing the dimension.